# Cookie Domain contains Dot?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, cookies

I use the Cookies class of GWT to generate cookies.

When I use the following

```
Cookies.setCookie(LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME, value, expires);
```

everything works fine. Checking the cookie in the browser leads to mydomay.com as it should.

But, when I use the following:

```
String path = "/"
String domain = "mydomain.com"
Cookies.setCookie(LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME, value, expires, domain, path, secure);
```

I can see a dot before the domain when I check it in my browser:

```
.mydomain.com
```

Where does the dot comes from?

It turns out that Cookies.removeCookie(LOGIN_COOKIE_NAME) does not work for me if .mydomain.com is given. Why is it not possible to delete this cookie when there is a dot in front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the expire date to now such that the cookie expires imidiately.

```
Cookies.setCookie(COOKIE_NAME, "", new Date(), domain, path, false);
```

Answer (score 11):

The dot means that the cookie also holds for any subdomain to `mydomain.com`, such as `example.mydomain.com`. Think of it as `*.mydomain.com` where * is a wildcard.

You can find a highly similar question here: [What is the cookie dot rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638497/what-is-the-cookie-dot-rule)

Comment: @confile That could be another issue which has been resolved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049467/remove-cookie-issue

Comment: When the cookie has domain: .mydomain.com I tried Cookies.removeCookie("cookieName", "/") but still I cannot remove the cookie. It must be because of the dot in front of the domain. Any idea?

Comment: @confile I'm sorry but I have no idea what could be the issue here. Could you give a complete code example that reproduces the unexpected behavior?

Comment: How do I fix my problem I want to have String domain = "mydomain.com"?

Answer (score 2):

If you passed a domain when it was created then, when you clear a cookie, you need to pass the same domain (e.g. [How do you remove a Cookie in a Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890935/how-do-you-remove-a-cookie-in-a-java-servlet)?); however, there's no API here to allow that.

This sounds a lot like a bug reported as [RFE: Provide a Cookies.removeCookie(name, domain, path) method](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4108):

> A cookie is set on the server for a given URL and the domain name and path
>   are explicitly set on the cookie as part of the returned result. 
>   Cookies.remove(name) and Cookies.remove(name, path) will not remove the
>   cookie on FF3.0.14.  (The path based remove does work on IE 6).

The workaround suggested in that issue is to patch the GWT `Cookies` class.

Comment: How do I fix my problem I want to have String domain = "mydomain.com"?

Answer (score 1):

Dot here signifies that cookie also holds for a sub-domain, such as abcd.mydomain.com. IT is very similar to say that you can add an entirely different website onto your domain, say registration segment separated in a different sub-domain so in general it can be substituted with a wildcard say *.mydomain.com. This is referred to as Cookie Dot Rule. Refer to the [IETF Page](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt)  for the same. You can let the same cookie refer to multiple token values as well.

Comment: How do I fix my problem I want to have String domain = "mydomain.com"?